# how to solve sigma summation using python recursion method

Tags: python, math

how to create a python function that perform a calculation based on the following mathematical function using recursion method.

```
i=n 
∑i=1/(x^i)
i=1
```

Comment: Hint: this expands to `1/x + 1/x^2 + 1/x^3 + ... + 1/x^n`. How would you create a sequence of the necessary terms, then add them up?

Comment: define with python recursion method @chepner

Comment: Assuming this is homework, it's to your benefit to take the advice that you've been given and try to work through the problem yourself. Just asking someone else to write the code for you isn't going to help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can "unroll" the summation notation by removing an explicit term and adjusting the index.

```
i=n                  i=n
∑i=1/(x^i)  == 1/x + ∑i=1/(x^i)
i=1                  i=2
```

or

```
i=n                    i=n-1
∑i=1/(x^i)  == 1/x^n + ∑i=1/(x^i)
i=1                    i=1
```

From this, you should be able to figure out how to define the recursive function

```
def sum(lower, upper):
    ...
```

assuming you know how to evaluate either

```
i=n 
∑i=1/(x^i)
i=n
```

or

```
i=1
∑i=1/(x^i)
i=1
```

directly.